# $.ajax not working first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button in html page.

```
<input type="image" src="images/login_button.png" id="imageButton" onclick="LoginButtonClick();" />
```

I am calling this method on button click:

```
LoginButtonClick = function() {
    alert ("Button click event raised");  // this alert msg raising every time when onclick event occurs.
    $.ajax({  
        alert ("Inside Ajax.");  // This alert not executing first 1 or 2 times.
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://URL/Service.svc/LoginValidation',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: pmamml.ajaxError,
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (response != "") {
                alert ("Response receive ");
                }
            else {
                alert("Invalid Data.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As I mentioned above `$.ajax` not working first 2 , 3 button click attempts.

In mozilla it throws an error "[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: JQuery.js ::  :: line 20"  data: no]"

Is there any way to fix this issues..

Comment: what about your return alerts? do they work always?

Comment: Is your server method returning json or text? If text, then set dataType='text'.

Comment: Thanks Onheiron.. No.. return alrets not firing.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why it *is* executing later. But here's the deal--you're placing the alert in the object literal that defines the parameters for the .ajax method. It doesn't belong there. Try putting the alert in your success and/or error handlers.

**UPDATE**

How long are you waiting? When you initiate an ajax request, it isn't going to hang the UI. It could be that you're seeing the result of the first click on your 3rd or 4th attempt and think that you're triggering it on that 3rd or 4th attempt.

Comment: thanks Brian.. I tried with alert box inside success and error. Even this is not calling first 2,3 times.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.ajax()` function receives as a parameter a set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. I don't think that the syntax will be correct by placing the `alert()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** - entering an absolute path isnt going to work if the domain is not the current one - it is against the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that browsers adhere too - this might explain why nothing happens when its executed - i suggest you look in your browser debugger to verify.

You should be binding the click event like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imageButton').click(function() {
    // code here
  });
});
```

so your complete code will look like this :

HTML

```
<input type="image" src="images/login_button.png" id="imageButton" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#imageButton').click(function () {
    alert("Button click event raised"); // this alert msg raising every time when onclick event occurs.
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://URL/Service.svc/LoginValidation',
      dataType: 'json',
      error: pmamml.ajaxError,
      success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (response != "") {
          alert("Response receive ");
        } else {
          alert("Invalid Data.");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I have removed the `alert ("Inside Ajax.");` line as this will not be executed - you pass an object `{}` of parameters not code to execute. If you want to execute before the ajax request is sent do this :

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function() {
     alert('inside ajax');
   }
   // other options here
});
```

[Docs for the `$.ajax()` function are here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: This is a nice, comprehensive description; however, he seems to indicate that he gets a response eventually, so the note at the top is likely not pointing to the cause. But the rest is very good and well-organized.

Comment: Thanks Manse for the post. but unluckily $.ajax still not working properly for first 2, 3 attempts.. Its throwing ajax error as undefiend.

Comment: Its probably this line `error: pmamml.ajaxError,` change it to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus) });`

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you have the second alert in the wrong place, and dont know what pmamml.ajaxError function is but may be your call returns with error and therefore your success alerts are not firing. You can check with error and complete functions as follows:

```
LoginButtonClick = function() {
alert ("Button click event raised");  // this alert msg raising every time when onclick event occurs.
$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://URL/Service.svc/LoginValidation',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert ("ajax call returns error: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (response != "") {
            alert ("Response receive ");
            }
        else {
            alert("Invalid Data.");
        }
    },
   complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
         alert('completed with either success or fail');
    }
});
```

}

You can test with Google Chrome's Developer tools -> Network tab, if a request is made and returned (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)

Comment: Its throwing error inside ajax as "ajax call returns error: undefined" in Firefox. But IE its not showing this alert msg.

Comment: Are you clearing cache in IE? You can press F12->Cache tab->Always Refresh from server->F5 (to refresh page). Also you can use script debugging to further examine the error parameters you get: jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown